# Access denied for user with database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am beginning learner of laravel. When i am trying to execute the line

> php artisan migrate:install

shows the following error. i also change database.php file,but couldn't solve.

[PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'

Comment: Can you show us `app/config/database.php`? (don't forget to mask passwords)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12msw4WHdNuj8WS1N04zFbCBf5j_gfqquk1wCO1vQ59k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And are those values correct? Is your database called `forge` and the user `forge` with an empty password?

Comment: what you mean my this? i shared my database.php file? Do i need to check these somewhere else? i am using xampp and at phpmyadmin,i check   these info in mysql.

Comment: Yes I looked at your `database.php` Those values are the default values. I just want to know if they are correct.

Comment: @lukasgeiter  thank you so much for your support. I checked my mysql info through phpmyadmin and there is a little mistake. I selected anyhost instead of localhost. After this correction migration table created successfully.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. If you think this could help future visitors of this post, please add an answer :)

Comment: check host option whick one is selected,i mean localhost,anyhost or hostname as well as other optiops like password,username having all privilege.

Comment: Okay. By add an answer I meant writing a real answer using the big **Answer Your Question** button at the bottom left of this page :)